# How to use findOne in Template onCreated and access it in helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-collections

Here is my template onCreated and helper function.  I have provided inline comments to add some clarity.  I can see that self.post is eventually set because it shows up on my console when I log Template.instance().  However, when I log Template.instance().post, it is always undefined.

```
Template.default.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
        var postId = FlowRouter.getParam('post_id');
        self.subscribe('onePost', postId);
        self.post = Posts.findOne(FlowRouter.getParam('post_id'));
    });
});
Template.default.helpers({
    poststage: function(stage) {
        console.log(Template.instance()); // I can see post object here
        console.log(Template.instance().post; //always undefined
        if(Template.instance().post) {
            // never true
            return Template.instance().post.stage == stage;
        }
    }
});
Template.default.events({
    'submit form':function(event, instance) {
        Meteor.call('someFunc', instance.post.anotherField);
    }
});
```

Edit:  I should add, I'm trying to avoid writing the query twice because I'm also using it in the Template events.  (see code).

Comment: Reactivevar might help, on the meteorchef reactive

Comment: findOne is reactive by default.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a timing issue. You are subscribing to the `onePost` publication but you aren't waiting for that subscription to be `.ready()` before assigning `self.post` The `autorun` also seems superfluous. You shouldn't need to rerun that block of code in the `onCreated` block. I suggest:

```
Template.default.onCreated(function() {
  this.postId = FlowRouter.getParam('post_id');
  self.subscription = subscribe('onePost', this.postId);
});
Template.default.helpers({
  poststage: function(stage) {
    if ( this.subscription.ready()  ){
      return Posts.findOne(this.postId).stage;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, yes, this is how I would normally have done it, but I'm reusing the query later in the code (in the events).  I was actually thinking of rewording the question to reflect this (which I will do now).  The answer may be just write Posts.findOne... again.  But, I was thinking why query twice?

Comment: minimongo queries are relatively cheap, often cheaper than coding yourself into corners trying to optimize them out. You can also query for the data context in the containing template and then you have the query result in `this`

Comment: Ok, I am going to just query twice.  I will leave this question open and probably reword it a little bit to try and specify how to write one query and use it in the Template onCreated, helpers and events.  The most frustrating thing is that my post is available in console.log(Template.instance()); but not in Template.instance().post.   I know it becomes available, but it should be logging when it becomes available....  oh well...

Comment: I suspect it's there in the structure at first but if you drill into it you will see it's undefined and then only later becomes defined.

Comment: It is defined as an object containing the document, but I'm VERY SURE you're right about the timing thing....  I just thought if(Template.instance().post) { within the helper would basically do the same thing as if ( this.subscription.ready() ) { in your example.  Again, I'm convinced it is a timing thing as well.